# $filter upto 2 nested level in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework

i have a database structured like this:

```html
{
  "Hospitais": [
    {
      "utis": [
        {
          "_id": 893910,
          "nome": "UTI1",
          "leitos": [
            {
              "_id": 128938120,
              "_paciente": "Oliver"
            },
            {
              "_id": 12803918239,
              "_paciente": "Priscilla"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "_id": 38471839,
          "nome": "UTI2",
          "leitos": [
            {
              "_id": 48102938109,
              "_paciente": "Serveró"
            },
            {
              "_id": 501293890,
              "_paciente": "Thales"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "_id": 58109238190,
          "nome": "UTI3",
          "leitos": [
            {
              "_id": 93801293890,
              "_paciente": "Lucia"
            },
            {
              "_id": 571029390,
              "_paciente": "Amanda"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "nome": "Dorio Silva"
    },
    {
      "utis": [
        {
          "_id": 410923810,
          "nome": "UTI1",
          "leitos": [
            {
              "_id": 48102938190,
              "_paciente": "Neymar"
            },
            {
              "_id": 48102938190,
              "_paciente": "Thiago"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "_id": 41092381029,
          "nome": "UTI2",
          "leitos": [
            {
              "_id": 10293182309,
              "_paciente": "Brazza"
            },
            {
              "_id": 38190238,
              "_paciente": "Pelé"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "_id": 83102938109,
          "nome": "UTI3",
          "leitos": [
            {
              "_id": 810923810,
              "_paciente": "Aparecida"
            },
            {
              "_id": 20938904209,
              "_paciente": "Pimentinha"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "nome": "Apart Hospital"
    }
]
}
```

I need to return just the array of Hospitais that have a match with a input of 'Hospitais.nome' and also, there is a array inside each array of Hospitais called 'utis', i want to filter it too together, **there is a "Expected Result" bellow**.

I have tried this from many different ways and the most recent one i've been trying is this code :

```
db.collection.aggregate(
[
    { "$match": { "Hospitais.nome": 'Dorio Silva'} },
    {
        "$project": {
            _id: 0,
            Hospitais: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$Hospitais",
                    as: "hospital",
                    cond: { $and: [{$eq: ["$$hospital.nome", 'Dorio Silva']},{ $eq: ["$$hospital.utis.nome",'UTI1']}]}
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

);

As far as i understood about aggregation filter, it should only show the objects of the array Hospitais where Hospital.nome is 'Dorio Silva' and the object of Hospital.utis where Hospital.utis.nome is 'UTI1'

What i was expecting:

```html
[
 {
  "utis" : [
   {
    "_id" : NumberInt("893910"),
    "nome" : "UTI1",
    "leitos" : [
     {
      "_id" : NumberInt("128938120"),
      "_paciente" : "Oliver"
     },
     {
      "_id" : NumberLong("12803918239"),
      "_paciente" : "Priscilla"
     }
    ]
   }
  ],
  "nome" : "Dorio Silva"
 }
]
```

But thats never the result, i can post the results if asked, but i don't think it may be needed.
**What is the right way to query my result?** Is there anything wrong with the way i'm building my database? It could be done better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the first array then you can easily apply [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) on the nested array

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$Hospitais" },
  { "$match": { "Hospitais.nome": "Dorio Silva" } },
  { "$project": {
    "Hospitais": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$Hospitais.utis",
        "as": "uti",
        "cond": {
          "$eq": ["$$uti.nome", "UTI1"]
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Or you can try this as well

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "Hospitais.nome": "Dorio Silva" } },
  { "$project": {
    "Hospitais": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": {
          "$map": {
            "input": "$Hospitais",
            "as": "hospital",
            "in": {
              "nome": "$$hospital.nome",
              "utis": {
                "$filter": {
                  "input": "$$hospital.utis",
                  "as": "uti",
                  "cond": {
                    "$eq": ["$$uti.nome", "UTI1"]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "as": "hospital",
        "cond": {
          "$eq": ["$$hospital.nome", "Dorio Silva"]
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Both will give the similar output

```
[
  {
    "Hospitais": [
      {
        "_id": 893910,
        "leitos": [
          {
            "_id": 1.2893812e+08,
            "_paciente": "Oliver"
          },
          {
            "_id": 1.2803918239e+10,
            "_paciente": "Priscilla"
          }
        ],
        "nome": "UTI1"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: It worked, but if i wanted to do a third filter? "Hospitais.nome": "Dorio Silva" , "Hospital.utis.nome" : "UTI1" and "Hospital.utis.leitos._paciente" : "Priscilla" ? i tried doing : 

 "cond": { $and: [{ $eq: ["$$uti.nome", 'UTI1'] }, { $eq: ["$$uti.leitos._paciente", 'Ol iver'] }] } 

But there was no matches, the logic is wrong?

Comment: You will have to use `$unwind` once more to drill into the `leitos` array

Comment: How do i use unwind twice? in the same query?